# $scope update across different modules on $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

#### How do I update one module's $scope member from another module's $http.success()?

This is going to be a tough one to explain, so I'll do my best.

I have two modules, `HeaderApp` and `ContentApp`.  Essentially, `HeaderApp` controls the breadcrumbs and navigation heading the web app, and `ContentApp` is the "content", if you will.

For reasons I don't really want to get deep into, `ContentApp` has to refresh every 30 seconds or so to keep the information up to date.

These modules are almost completely independent of each other, except that every time `ContentApp` refreshes its data, a `refresh_time` timestamp needs to be updated in the header.

Here's one variation of what I've tried:

html

```
<div ng-app="HeaderApp">
    <div ng-controller="Header">
        <span> Updated: {{refresh_time}} </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-app="ContentApp">
    <div ng-controller="Content">
        <div ng-repeat="row in data"> {{row.content}} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var HeaderApp = angular.module("HeaderApp", [])
.controller("Header", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.refresh_time = new Date().toString();
    window.update_refresh_time = function() {
        $scope.refresh_time = new Date().toString();
        $scope.$apply(); //this is throwing an error in console
    }
}]);

var ContentApp = angular.module("ContentApp", [])
.controller("Content", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope,$http,$timeout) {
    (function repeatMe() {
        
        $http(...)
        .success(function(data) {

            $scope.data = data;
            window.update_refresh_time();
            $timeout(repeatMe, 30000);

        }).error(...);
    })();
}]);

//manual bootstrapping...
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['HeaderApp', 'BUOverviewApp']);
});
```

Other variations I've tried (after reading other posts on SO) include sharing a `factory` service across the modules via `angular.module("ContentApp", ["HeaderApp"])` and employing `$rootScope`.

When I check the javascript console, I get three consecutive errors that [look like this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest).  I read the entire page and it didn't really make sense.  When I read other comments regarding the appropriate time to use `$apply()`, it seems to me like any time you get this `already in progress` error is a time that it should theoretically be unnecessary to invoke it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$rootScope.$on` and `$rootScope.$broadcast` and I don't think `apply()` is needed here, it will fire error if used when it shouldn't be.

```
var HeaderApp = angular.module("HeaderApp", [])
.controller("Header", ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.refresh_time = new Date().toString();
    $rootScope.$on("refresh_time", function() {
        $scope.refresh_time = new Date().toString();
    });
}]);

var ContentApp = angular.module("ContentApp", [])
.controller("Content", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$timeout) {
    (function repeatMe() {

        $http(...)
        .success(function(data) {

            $scope.data = data;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("refresh_time");
            $timeout(repeatMe, 30000);

        }).error(...);
    })();
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$rootScope.broadcast()`?